# Combine --grep and -G options in git log

Tags: git, git-log

`git log` provides the `--grep` option to filter commits by commit *message*. It also provides `-G` or `-S` to filter commits by *changes* made in that commit. But is there a way to combine the two options using a Boolean OR?

Comment: If you need `OR`, would it be acceptable (I mean usable in your context) to just do both commands successively? It could be bundled into a single alias, for convenience.

Comment: @RomainValeri sure, that's acceptable if no other built-in option exists.

Comment: @Ionut Fair enough, let's see if someone suggests anything.

Comment: I did obtain what I wanted using `( git log --grep ...; git log -G ... ) | sort | uniq`, but a built-on option is always nice.

Comment: Still interested in a better-looking command !